# How to invert dictionary with multiple values of each key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been working on this forever. I have the following dictionary.

```
Subject1='Math'
Subject2='English'
Subject3='Chemstry'
Subject4='Physics'
Subject5='Geology'
Subject6='PE'
Subject7='Music'
Subject8='Psychology'
Subject9='Politics'
Subject10='Acting'

dict_1 = {(Subject1, Subject2):['Michael','James','Lydia'],
          (Subject3, Subject4):['Michael','Lydia','James'],
          (Subject5, Subject6):['Tom'],
          (Subject7, Subject8):[],
          (Subject9, Subject10):[]
}
```

I want to inverse the dictionary so that it will look like:

```
{['Michael', 'James', 'Lydia']: {(Subject1, Subject2), (Subject3, Subject4)}, 
 ['Tom']: {(Subject5, Subject6)}, 
 []: {(Subject7, Subject8), (Subject9, Subject10)} }
```

I tried

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_tel = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in dict_1.items():
    new_tel[value].append(key)
```

This worked for hashable type but not unhashable type list. Maybe I can join the string of `['Michael','James','Lydia']` to `'James Lydia Michael`' so that it can be a valid key? How do I sort the elements in the list `['Michael','James','Lydia']` and `['Michael','Lydia','James']` so that they are in alphabetical order before I join them?

This is a more achievable output:

```
{'James Lydia Michael': {(Subject1, Subject2), (Subject3, Subject4)}, 
 'Tom': {(Subject5, Subject6)}, 
 'None': {(Subject7, Subject8), (Subject9, Subject10)} }
```

Comment: You can't use a list as a dictionary key.

Comment: ... but you can use a tuple instead

Comment: Dictionary keys are immutable I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary keys can't be lists but it can be tuples. So you can do something like below. Sort the values, make them tuples to use as keys and use `dict.setdefault`:

```
out = {}
for k,v in dict_1.items():
    out.setdefault(tuple(sorted(v)), set()).add(k)
```

Output:

```
{('James', 'Lydia', 'Michael'): {('Chemstry', 'Physics'), ('Math', 'English')},
 ('Tom',): {('Geology', 'PE')},
 (): {('Music', 'Psychology'), ('Politics', 'Acting')}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As told in the question comments lists are unhashable. if you can use tuple instead, "Dict Comprehensions" is a good way. More info: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/.

```
dict_reverse = {tuple(dict_1[key]): key for key in dict_1.keys()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to use a `tuple` as key type

```
for key, value in dict_1.items():
    new_tel[tuple(sorted(value))].append(key)


{('James', 'Lydia', 'Michael'): [('Math', 'English'), ('Chemstry', 'Physics')], 
 ('Tom',): [('Geology', 'PE')],  
 (): [('Music', 'Psychology'), ('Politics', 'Acting')]})
```

---

If you join to set the key type as `str`

```
for key, value in dict_1.items():
    new_tel[" ".join(sorted(value))].append(key)


{'James Lydia Michael': [('Math', 'English'), ('Chemstry', 'Physics')], 
 'Tom': [('Geology', 'PE')], 
 '': [('Music', 'Psychology'), ('Politics', 'Acting')]})
```